# My poor Vincent, weird knees make it look like robocop

Tags: animation

I am practicing walk cycles and picked the poor Vincent because I am a bad puppeteer!

I made him walk as robocop does, this happens within the frames 30 and 50/60 and the knee movement is very weird and then it reflects on the leg.

[image: Blender Screenshot of Vincent walk cycle keyframes]

[image: This is what I've used for reference]

I really cannot tell where I am doing this wrong, again I am a noob in the Blender world.

You can see how bad it looks on the [gyazo gif of robotic Vincent GIF](https://gyazo.com/b9c4949463994fa64a4e8aebd17b9266)

I saw on the other thread someone say it was about hip movement, I did moved the hips but it may be that it wasn't enough.

Can someone teach me where am I failing?

[Blender file of Vincent in zippyshare](https://www36.zippyshare.com/v/Ybd6LmYT/file.html)

Comment: providing blend file would help

Comment: There's a very detailed walk cycle tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZ14vidzSs4) which is a bit long-winded but goes through all the steps to produce a realistic walk.

Comment: @Chris I am attaching on the original thread the blender file with the keyframes of Vincent at the moment I stopped. Thanks for reaching out to help

Comment: Download not working? Relaxed bipedal walking in the able-bodied is: repeatedly falling over. Maybe think about the relative forward position of the hips and the tilt of the torso in those terms: where are the _weights_, that help the drop onto the next foot-fall, and the momentum which will take you beyond it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following things, still not perfect but a bit better I think:

[image]

- Its lowest position (when the hip is at the lowest position) should be at frame 1 (and 40, the reverse pose), when its legs are spread the most, so you need to correct that:

[image]

- Also lift a bit the hip on the next pose (frame 10 and 50), to make the transition to its highest position (which happens at frame 20 and 60):

[image]

- Maybe he should not bend forward but stay straight? Give it a try:

[image]

- At the intermediate position, put the up foot here:

[image]

- When he's about to put his front feet, it should be a bit lifted like that, also lower the knee a bit down:

[image]

- At last, you need to make the feet slide linearly on the ground, otherwise the feet will slide when you'll animate your character through the 3D space, see some tutorials on how to create a walk cycle with no sliding, here I've used an empty to help me make the foot slide nilearly:

[image]